# Multiple lines of code in variable jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables

I want to set html content and store it in a variable.
Is this the way to do is?:

```
var sugarContent = [
    $("div#ingredients h1 span").html("sugar"),
    $("div#ingredients img").attr("src", "content/sugar.jpg"),
    $("div#ingredients p").html("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit."),
];
```

I doubt it because later I want to fadeIn() sugarContent, and that doesn't work.
But it does work if I fadeIn() every line of code apart, instead of use the variable.

Please, help me out!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: this will create an array 3 jQuery obejcts... what is the result you are looking for

Comment: Can you post the code that performs the fade effect? You may be invoking jQuery methods on the array itself, which indeed won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You must store the jquery element into a variable not the content if you want to use it for methods like fadeIn.

```
$("div#ingredients h1 span").html("sugar");
$("div#ingredients img").attr("src", "content/sugar.jpg");
$("div#ingredients p").html("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.");
var $sugar = $("div#ingredients");
$sugar.fadeIn();
```